# UITextField is not editable Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have implemented the UITextFieldDelegateand set isUserInteractionEnabled to true, but the textField is still not editable, some advice?

```
lazy var myTextField: UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    text.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    text.backgroundColor = .white
    text.textColor = .black
    text.borderStyle = .line
    text.placeholder = "Enter your text"

    return text
}()

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: maybe some view covered the textfield

Comment: show your view hierarchy